# Slow performance of DateTimeOffset.Parse?

Tags: c#, datetime, optimization

I'm querying from my database and doing the following function for each Row in the Table. I have around 400,000 rows.

It seems that the DateTimeOffset.Parse is taking a lot of time when I analyzed performance using VS built-in tool. Other properties that have different type (ex. string, int, bool) takes much less.

Is there a way to optimize the performance for DateTimeOffset.Parse?

```
private MyItem GetMyItemData()
    {
        var entity = new MyItem();

        //**** Lots of setting other entity properties****

        entity.ActiveDate =
           string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DataManager.Reader["ActiveDate"].ToString()) ?
           DateTimeOffset.MinValue : DateTimeOffset.Parse(this.DataManager.Reader["ActiveDate"].ToString());


        return entity;
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: What format is the `ActiveDate` field in the source?  You are converting to string then to DateTimeOffset... is there a better conversion option that is more direct?  For instance if the field is a `DateTime` (which you can test with `is DateTime` then converting that directly to a `DateTimeOffset` is a lot faster than converting to string and back again.

Comment: Thanks Corey, I think the conversion option provided by peer is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the format of the incoming string the TryParseExact will probably give you better performance.

A comparison of different functions: [DateTime parsing performance](http://blog.joachim.at/?p=42)

You should write some tests your self to verify this for DateTimeOffset.

You are doing this twice, which is maybe costly in a large datastructure:

```
this.DataManager.Reader["ActiveDate"].ToString()
```

rewite it to:

```
string activedatestr = this.DataManager.Reader["ActiveDate"].ToString();
entity.ActiveDate =
       string.IsNullOrEmpty(activedatestr) ?
       DateTimeOffset.MinValue : DateTimeOffset.**Parse**(activedatestr);
```

Comment: Thanks peer, the TryParseExact helped in reducing the time.